# Trying to match a regular expression on a website using Mechanize and python

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, mechanize-python

I'm trying to eventually populate a google sheet from data I'm scraping from wikipedia. ( I'll deal with the robots.txt file later I'm just trying to figure out how to do this conceptually. My code is below. I'm trying to put the page in as a string and then run a regexp search my goal is to isolate the specs on the page and at least store them as a value but I'm having a problem searching the page keeps coming up as did not find

Be gentle I'm a noob - Thanks in advance for your help!

```
import mechanize
import re
import gspread


br = mechanize.Browser()

pagelist=["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_Model_S"]

wheelbase = ''
length =''
width= ''
height =''





pages=len(pagelist)
i=0



br.open(pagelist[0])

page = br.response()
print page.read()

pageAsaString = str(page.read())



match = re.search('Wheelbase',pageAsaString)
if match:                      
    print 'found', match.group() 
else:
print 'did not find'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the page just fine - the reason that you're getting a message saying that the page couldn't be found is because your `print 'did not find'` block isn't properly indented. This matters in Python! Bump it over 4 spaces:

```
if match:                      
    print 'found', match.group() 
else:
    print 'did not find'
```

There's one other thing. I'm not familiar with Mechanize, but you're just calling `read()` on the page, which exhausts it. So, when you `read()` the page in `print page.read()`, there isn't anything left to consume and assign to `pageAsaString`. You've already read to the end of the page! So you'll want to read the page and save it to a variable first. Check out the documentation for IO operations [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

After fixing the indentation and removing `print page.read()`, everything appeared to work just fine.

Since you're starting out, I highly recommend reading [Dive Into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/). Good luck with your project!

Comment: You're quite welcome. It was a great start for me.

After a little more reading, Mechanize looks like it's a fancy wrapper around [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html). So, when it gets a response, it [returns a file-like object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen). Thus, calling `read()` on it exhausts it, much like a file on your system. Subsequent calls to `read()` start from where the last one left off - at the end of the buffer. :)

Comment: Do you know of a way to actually parse to the wheelbase value to store it as a variable?

Comment: considering going down this road http://palewi.re/posts/2008/04/20/python-recipe-grab-a-page-scrape-a-table-download-a-file/

Comment: You're already saving the page contents with `pageAsaString = str(page.read())` - except you don't actually need to convert it to a string, since `read` already returns a string. In the tutorial you linked to, the page contents are read and assigned to a variable with `html = page.read()`. From there, you could `print html`, match a regex against it, etc. Or do you mean extracting the value associated with your regex, i.e. the actual dimensions?

Comment: Well, either way, I think that tutorial you linked gives a good start, and will answer (and provoke) many questions. Using a parser like `BeautifulSoup` is a heck of a lot easier than trying to manually parse HTML with regexes. That's a pretty famously painful thing to do. :)

Comment: Thanks so much Cole, I'll try BS and see how far I can get...I do think I'm going to learn a lot on this project. (read:struggle)